# Stop Work My Android Application When The Admin Sends Request From my Server to His Androidapp?

Tags: android

I have a doubt i.e how to stop my application when i send the request from my server to my android application .The application should not work in that android device on receiving such command from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Setup [GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)
2. Have a predefined GCM message that acts as the stop signal
3. When you receive the message, stop the app from working.

Alternative method (without GCM)

1. Have your app access a webservice or text file or something on a remote server each time it starts up
2. If the response from the server equals, say, 1 then keep working. If the response is 0, then stop the app from working.